# Removing UIImageView if the user taps on any point outside the UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

My app shows an `UIView` which contains four `UIButtons`, one of them removes the `UIView`, but I also need is to remove the `UIView`, including all containing buttons when the user taps outside it.
This is how I remove the `UIView` using a button action:

```
-(IBAction)closeSideTasks: (id)sender
{
    UIView * backgroundView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:7];
    [backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Any help or advice is welcome.

MORE INFORMATION:

This is the scenario: there is a table view. If the user swipes from left to right on a row, then the UIView appears on the right side of the view. The UIView *newView is removed after tapping on each of the buttons inside it and executing each button action. But may be the user does not tap on any of the buttons, and the UIView remains on the view. Then, what I want to achieve is a way that the UIView *newView gets removed if the user taps anywhere outside it, to prevent that it remains always on the view...

Comment: So if `closeSideTasks:` removes the UIImageView, then call it when the user taps in the place where you want. You will probably want to set up a UITapGestureRecognizer in order to determine when that happens...

Comment: Create a transparant button underneath the UIImageView that is full screen that calls this function on touchDown. Make sure you remember to remove the button along with the view

Comment: @matt, thank you, I have updated my question to give more information.

Comment: @JackWu, thank you, I have updated my question to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
                    tapGesture.delegate = self;
                    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                    [tapGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(tapChangeImage)];

                    [self.profileImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Now add the action method:

```
#pragma tap gestures
-(void)tapChangeImage{
    // Remove view from superview!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and what happens using your proposal if the user taps anywhere (row, section header,etc) and the UIView *newView is not shown?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. But i dont think that `removeFromSuperview´returns a exception if it doesn't exist. You have to try out.

Comment: That works, I have included your first piece inside the method where I call the UIView, and it works as required, thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Put a large button, full screen, with no graphics, no text, and a clear background. Have its action also remove the background

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question to give more information.